# Посоветуйте библиотеку ручной сортировки блоков как в ВК

Tags: javascript

В вконтакте при редактировании своих аудиозаписей, можно перетаскивать мышкой разные композиции и раставлять в различном порядке. Посоветуйте либу на javascript с подобным функцоналом.
Могу и на jquery сделать, но мне надо чтоб либу в код вставил, натравил либу на нужные блоки и оно заработало.
Нужно чтобы ещё элементы в списке вели себя так же как в ВК, т.е. происходила мгновенная пересортировка.

Comment: > мне надо чтоб либу в код вставил,
> натравил либу на нужные блоки и оно
> заработало

м-да, желание помогать отпало...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А стандартные UI jQuery не подходя? [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid)

Comment: То что нужно, уважаемый!)) спасибочки.